# Subtract a number according to Drop Down list options

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I would like to subtract a number according to Drop Down list options.  My Drop Down list is in columns B4 to B20 and each column has the same tree options: A-B-C , and there are columns D4 to D20 and F4 to F20 each column with exact numbers in reference to those options. Columns G4 TO G20 are the subtraction results. If option A is chosen i want to subtract F(column number) - D(Column number) = G(Column number) , If option B is chosen i want to subtract to subtract D(Column number) - F(Column number) = G(Column number), option C would be the same as B, subtract D(Column number) - F(Column number) = G(Column number). Just an example: in column B4 i choose option B from the Drop down list, than:  D4 - F4 = G4.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add below formula in G2 and copy it down to G20

```
=IF(B2="A",F2-D2,IF(B2="B",D2-F2,IF(B2="C",D2-F2,"n/a")))
```